# How to show a and hide a widget when a special symbol is inputted on the textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I am listening to changes of the textfield using the `onChanged` property of the textfield to detect when **@** symbol is pressed. It's just like a mention feature in every other social apps. I want to know when **@** symbol is pressed alongside other values and then show a mention widget until space is entered, then remove the mention widget.

**What i want to achieve**

1. Detect when **@** symbol is pressed, then show the mention widget, if another value is entered then remove the mention widget.
2. If **@** is detected in the middle of texts show mention widget

**What i have tried**

I use `regEx` to detect the values with **@** and print the matched value. I don't really know how to show the mention widget at the first regEx logic. I then split the textfield values and use a different `regEx` pattern to check if any value matched then show the mention widget.

It doesn't work as expected. When scrolled to the middle of the texts in the textfields and add **@** to a text, the mention widget doesn't trigger.

**onChanged property code**

```
 void onChanged(String value) { 
    final _mentionRegEx = RegExp(AppUtils.mentionPattern, caseSensitive: false);
    final _checkRegEx = RegExp(
      r"^@[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$",
      // caseSensitive: false,
      multiLine: true,
    );
    Iterable<Match> matches = _mentionRegEx.allMatches(value);

    for (var m in matches) {
      String match = m[0]!;
      final withoutMentonTag = match.substring(1);
      state = state.copyWith(matched: withoutMentonTag);
      print('MENTION => ${state.matched}');
    }

    final sentences = value.split(' ');
    for (var sentence in sentences) {
      print('SENTENCE => $sentence');
      final words = sentence.split(' ');
      final withMentionTag = words.last;

      if (_checkRegEx.hasMatch(sentence)) {
        toggleMentionWidget(true);
        String withoutMentionTag = withMentionTag.substring(1);
        print('MENTIONED USER => $withoutMentionTag');
      } else {
        toggleMentionWidget(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mentions?

Comment: "the mention widget doesn't trigger" - it's not clear whether you mean `toggleMentionWidget(true)` is not getting called, or it is getting called but is failing to show the widget.

Comment: @ChuckBatson it doesn't get called

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mentions) from pub.dev. It provides mention feature in an Input Text Field

```
FlutterMentions(
   key: key,
   suggestionPosition: SuggestionPosition.Top,
   maxLines: 5,
   minLines: 1,
   mentions: [
      Mention(
      trigger: "@",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
      data: [
         {
           "id": "61as61fsa",
           "display": "somename",
           "photo": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels- 
            photo-220453.jpeg"
         },
         {
           "id": "61asasgasgsag6a",
           "display": "username",
           "photo": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels- 
            photo-220453.jpeg",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          },
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: Copy of package example code

Comment: Just found out this one easier.

Comment: Already mention in comment of questions

Comment: @MilanSurelia I don't want to use packages. Moreover,  this package is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is incorrect:

```dart
    final _checkRegEx = RegExp(
      r"^@[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$",
      // caseSensitive: false,
      multiLine: true,
    );
```

Refer to the [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-assertion):

> ^ always matches only at the beginning of Input, or (if Multiline is true) at the beginning of a line.

Since your regular expression specifies `^` and `multiLine: true`, it will match only when the `@` character is at the beginning of the text, or the beginning of a line.

You may want to use a regular expression more like `(^@|\s@)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`. You may have to experiment to find a regular expression that does exactly what you want. You can try out different regular expressions at the site https://regex101.com.

If you continue to have difficulty, I suggest you open a new question tagged for regular expressions, since this has nothing to do with Dart or Flutter at this point.

Comment: How can I make it to match only the beginning of each words in the textfield?

Comment: Hello @MElochukwu, I've updated the answer with some information about regular expressions.